# React: How to set the cursor selection

Tags: reactjs

I am working with a custom library where I need to set the cursor selection manually. Here is the code for my input:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd'
import { Validation } from "../types";
...
  <input
    ref={forwardRef}
    id={id}
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    name={name}
    disabled={disabled}
    className={`fb-form-control goggo ${validation?.type}`}
    checked={!!checked}
    draggable={true}
    onDragStart={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
    onMouseEnter={()=>console.error("onMouseEnter", "onMouseEnter")}
    onMouseLeave={() => console.error("onMouseLeave", "onMouseLeave")}
    onDoubleClick={() => console.error("I have been double clicked!")}
  />
```

I need to replace the `() => console.error("I have been double clicked!")` with a call to a function that will select the text of the input. This code: `onDoubleClick={() => console.error("this", document.getElementById(String(id))?.select())}` causes a "`TS2551: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. Did you mean 'onselect'?`"

Comment: Did you try `onDoubleClick={() => (document.getElementById(String(id)) as HTMLInputElement)?.select()}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event target instead of getElementById.

```js
onDoubleClick={(event) => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).select()}
```

Comment: I tried that. I got: TS2339: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: Cast it as an element type and it should fix the error. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.getSelection` to select the text of the input:

```
onDoubleClick={() => {
  const input = document.getElementById(String(id)) as HTMLInputElement;
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(input);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}}
```

Comment: I tried that, I got: TS18047: 'selection' is possibly 'null'.

Comment: just add a check before and it should be ok

Comment: I added the check. The null error goes away, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I.e. the text simply does not get selected

Comment: could you provide a sandbox to reproduce ?

Comment: Sorry, no. A lot of the code is private and proprietary, I shared as much as I could. Thank you anyway @Johan! All the best!